# Docker: Manually Pushing to an Automated Build Repo

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm using a public automated docker build ([this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/bamos/openface/)).

I've made some changes to the repo, and I would like to be able to push the new image so that my other colleagues would be able to work on my updated version, for example by pulling galoosh33/my_openface instead of the original bamos/openface.

But, when I try to push my image I get an error:

```
unauthorized: authentication failed
```

I've searched for this error and from the staff answer on [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-pushing-to-registry-authentication-is-required/1534/23) page it seems like this is intentional:

> "Are you trying to push manually to an Automated Build repository? If so, you cannot do that, by design."

What are my options then?

Comment: Please show your push command.